# Processing payments code written in Swift 2, not sure about Swift 3 equivalent

Tags: ios, paypal, swift3, stripe-payments

So I have some code to process payments that I'm copying from a website:

```
if self.expireDateTextField.text.isEmpty == false {
    let expirationDate = self.expireDateTextField.text.componentsSeparatedByString("/")
    let expMonth = UInt(expirationDate[0].toInt()!)
    let expYear = UInt(expirationDate[1].toInt()!)
```

I know `toInt()` was removed but what be the equivalent of the code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Swift 3 equivalent of `toInt()` is simply `Int()`:

```
let expMonth = UInt(Int(expirationDate[0])!)!
let expYear = UInt(Int(expirationDate[1]!))!
```

In your case, I would make two refinements in the code. Firstly, you are converting two times, which is not neccesary, you may use `UInt()` only.

Secondly, you may consider not to implicitly unwrap, as it could easily cause a crash.

```
guard let expMonth = UInt(expirationDate[0]),
    let expYear = UInt(expirationDate[1]) else {
    print("Error in expiration casting")

    return
}
```